# “~&” Knows Whether the Ostream is At Line Head?

Tags: common-lisp, ostream, format-string

```
CL-USER> (progn
           (format t "abc~%")
           (format t "~&abc"))
abc
abc
NIL
CL-USER>
```

My guess is: An ostream descriptor always stores the latest char sent to it.
Say, after ostream receiving an `#\a`, `FORMAT` can determine that the ostream is **not** at the beginning because the latest char sent to it is `#\a`.

But I'm not sure that's really the case.

Comment: this depends on which implementation of the language you are using, the stream could hold a boolean "beginning-of-line-p" for example, or do as you said. The source code is. available for a lot of implementation, this is often interesting to read. For example some strings keep track of the current column: https://github.com/Clozure/ccl/blob/6c1a9458f7a5437b73ec227e989aa5b825f32fd3/cocoa-ide/cocoa-listener.lisp#L325

Comment: I forgot to say that I looked up for "fresh-line" because that's the actual function providing the feature, FORMAT just calls it when you have that directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~&` just calls `fresh-line`, so the question is in fact how does `fresh-line` know this, and the answer is

- it is not required to know it at all: see [TERPRI, FRESH-LINE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_terpri.htm);
- and how it knows it is entirely up to the implementation.

If you look at various implementations for which source is available you will probably find various ways they do this.  For instance SBCL has an `fd-stream` object (in [`src/code/fd-stream.lisp`](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/code/fd-stream.lisp)) which keeps track of the `output-column`.  But how implementations do this, and whether they do it at all, is up to them.